# Determine whether a Crystal Reports page contains a string

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to check whether a page in Crystal Reports contains a specific string ?

For example, I would like to search all pages for the word "Today" and if found on a page, show a Note reading "Text Found" on the page footer.

Comment: In a certain field or ALL fields on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this formula to the page-header section, then suppress it:

```
// {@reset}
// reset arrays
WhilePrintingRecords;
Booleanvar found:=false;
```

Add this formula to the details section, then suppress it;

```
// {@test}

WhilePrintingRecords;
Booleanvar found;

if Instr({table.field},"Today") > 0 Then found:=true;
```

Add this formula to the page-footer section:

```
// {@display}
// display the text that was found

WhilePrintingRecords;
Booleanvar found;

if found then "Text found";
```